# Replacing parts of an URL with value from a column

Tags: vba, excel, url, replace

I'm trying to download datasheets for horses.

The only variable in the macro is a part of the URL.

I have all the variables (the horses numbers) listed in column "A".

I want to create a new sheet with the information collected from the website, and then collect information again using the numbers (new variable) from next row in column "A".

So far this is the code I have:

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'
Dim nummer As String

nummer = Sheets("Ark1").Range("A1:A10")

'
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://195.198.34.45/trav/hast/visa/" & nummer & "/resultat", Destination:=Range _
        ("$A$1"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "resultat"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = True
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Columns("D:D").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=21
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Range("E22").Activate
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Range("D22").Activate
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon _
        :=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="/", _
        FieldInfo:=Array(1, 2), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

[User sheet trying to describe problem](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3318075/Heste.JPG)

Comment: I was with you until "and then do it for the next row in coulmn "A""- what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I guess im trying to create a multiple query. 
All the variables of the muliplequery is listed in coulmn A

Answer (score 0):

a proposition on how to handle multiple query, not sure about what you want to do with each result

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'sheet containing your numbers in column A
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    For Each nummer In ws.Range("A1:A10")
    If nummer.Text = "" Then Exit For
        For Each qt In ActiveSheet.QueryTables
            qt.Delete
        Next
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "URL;http://195.198.34.45/trav/hast/visa/" & nummer.Text & "/resultat", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
            .Name = "resultat"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = True
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            nummer.Offset(0, 1) = ActiveSheet.Cells(21, 1)
        End With
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank your for your help.

There is a problem, with the 2nd and 3rd query i think..

From my understanding this:

´Set ws = ActiveSheet`

means that it will use the active sheet in the next query, but i want it to use the number in the next row of my "main" sheet.

Comment: I have tried to add a little to my original post and added a picture.

I will later use the data collected for further processing

Thank  you

Comment: I have edited the code to put the name found next to the nummer

Comment: Thanks, thats a neat feature!

But now it doesnt generate a new sheet containing all the data..

Comment: just remove the instruction activesheet.delete